# Program exit status conventions

Tags: linux, windows, exit-code, errno, getlasterror

What is conventional return values for applications in Windows and GNU/Linux respectivly. 0 means success. But what should be used on user-requested abort. When I abort on Windows, it returns 3, but this value is not in the list of system error codes if it is not an ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND. GNU binutils uses 1. From a user perspective, returning GetLastError or errno would be good since they are documented, but is these only seems to cover lower level status codes. I am looking for a value that represents "Application terminated unsuccessfully"

The reason I wounder is that I want to

```
exit(errcode)
```

from a signal handler that catches some Access Violation/SIGSEGV (i.e programming errors) after printing a message about where it occured. Then the error code should be destiguishable from user input errors.

Comment: Exit code of non-zero implies *unsuccessful termination*.

Comment: Well since -1 is nonzero, and is not an already used error code it is fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might help, http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html those are the standard exit code. The rest of them I think are program dependant. basically you need to verify the documentation of the specific software you are looking for. As @devnull said, any exit code that is not zero implies an unsuccessful termination

Comment: For completeness, exit code 125 means "not the error we are looking for" to git-bisect. It should be perfectly fine to misuse this value for any other purpose — it only matters in one-off scripts running under git-bisect, for seeking out a specific error, and they must control their exit status tightly anyway.

Answer (score 4):

This is only few conventions about exit codes. Let's see what some manuals say:

**The GNU C Library Reference Manual**

> 1. There are conventions for what sorts of status values certain programs should return. 
>      The most common convention is simply 0 for success and 1 for failure
>      ...
> 2. A general convention reserves status values 128 and up for special purposes
> 3. Some non-POSIX systems use different conventions for exit status
>      values
> 4. For greater portability, you can use the macros **EXIT_SUCCESS** and **EXIT_FAILURE**
>      for the conventional status value for success and failure.

**ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (C11 standard)**

> If the value of status is **zero** or **EXIT_SUCCESS**, an implementation-defined form of the status *successful* termination is returned. If the value of status is **EXIT_FAILURE**, an implementation-defined form of the status *unsuccessful* termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.

That means if you want (and for most cases that's enough) just indicate success or failure you definitely should use **EXIT_SUCCESS** and **EXIT_FAILURE**. If you want indicate other errors, you should reinvent your own exit statuses. For example:

```
#define HEX_FILE_CREATE 2
#define HEX_FILE_CREATE 3
...
```

There is additional tips on what and how you should return:

> 1. **Warning:** Don’t try to use the number of errors as the exit status. This is actually not
>      very useful; a parent process would generally not care how many errors occurred. Worse
>      than that, it does not work, because the status value is truncated to eight bits. Thus, if
>      the program tried to report 256 errors, the parent would receive a report of 0 errors—that
>      is, success
> 2. For the same reason, it does not work to use the value of errno as the exit status—these
>      can exceed 255

**Conclusion:**

1. For success always use **EXIT_SUCCESS**
2. Your failure exit status should be beetween 1 and 127
3. Don't use **errno** error code as exit status